# Different behavior between multi-line vs. in-line block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am curious why these are producing different outputs. The desired output is an array of ActiveRecord records.

When using an in-line block, it appears to be doing the ActiveRecord lookup, but subsequently nests the original array (minus the `reject`ed elements) inside of another array and appends the nested arrays to the variable.

When using a multi-line block, the expected behavior occurs, i.e. the ActiveRecord lookup occurs and the identified records are appended to the variable.

```
x = []
y = ["", "1353", "1155"]
x << y.reject!(&:empty?).each { |i| User.find(i) }
# => ["1353", "1155"]
x
#=> [["1353", "1155"]]
```

vs

```
x = []
y = ["", "1353", "1155"]
y.reject!(&:empty?)
y.each do |i|
  x << User.find(i)  
end  
# => ["1353", "1155"]
x
#=> [#<User:0x00007fc7fbacc928
#  id: 1353,
#  login: nil,
...
```

Comment: This is a very silly way of doing `User.find(y.compact_blank)` as it will result in 3 database queries instead of one. The use of `each` and mutating an external variable is generally frowned upon in Ruby. Use `map`, `select` or any of the enumerable methods that return a result instead of you're transforming an array.

Comment: It's not multiline vs. inline. Your code examples are not equivalent at all. In the 1st example `x <<` is outside the `each` block and in the 2nd example it's inside the `each` block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that .each returns the array itself, so

```ruby
[1,2,3].each { nil }
# [1,2,3]
```

so you are appending the rejected Y numbers in X, and your .each is being useless on the first example (that's also why it is an array of array, because '<<' inserts the element array inside your array, and not all the individual elements)

---

In your second example, your 'each' is in fact appending the elements to your array inside the block, so no "return" dependency. If you want to do it on single line, you would have to do

```ruby
y.reject(&:empty?).each { |i| x << User.find(i) }
```

so it would do the calculation inside de block and if you want each loop to return the value inside the block you should use 'map' instead of 'each', and the 'concat' or '+' to sum the arrays (so it sums or concats each individual elements), so

```rb
x.concat(y.reject(&:empty?).map{ |i| User.find(i) })
```

---

OBS: As @tadman suggested on comment, I also removed the "bangs" for reject, as the 'reject!' method does not expect to always return all the values, check his comment for more information

Comment: This is a good first step, but don't forget about [`filter_map`](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/enumerable#method-i-filter_map) which can do this in one pass. It's also very important to note that `reject!` *will return `nil` if no values were removed* which means it cannot be chained. This should be `reject`.

Comment: Never seen the `filter_map` enumerable before and I find it even more interesting for this case, great comment! , the `reject!` does not return me `nil` in my ruby version, but removing the 'bang' signal surely optimizes it since it's not stored anywhere, thanks!

Comment: Note the difference between `[1,2,3].reject!(&:nil?)` and `[1,nil,3].reject!(&:nil?)`.

Comment: Wow, it only returns if it has rejected anything at all, that is new for me, I really appreciate it man, just edited the answer!

Comment: Yeah, it can be surprising. Code like this can work for years, then "suddenly" blow up, so it's important to be aware of it. A lot of `!` in-place style methods aren't suitable for chaining because of this.

Comment: This answer explains pretty well why the code doesn't work but but it doesn't really touch on the fact that its not how you should solve it in the first place as it results in N number of db queries instead of one. You can just do `User.find(y.compact_blank)` as `.find` takes an array or  you can use `.where` if you don't want an exception to be raised if any of the ids are not in the database.